# AJAX request not updating SQL Server database

Tags: ajax, sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I have a form with allows the user to edit data in the database using Ajax and ASP. Not sure why the ajax call is not updating the database as requested.

AJAX/jQuery code:

```
$('#editbtn').click(function(){
        var thisid = $('#edsid').val();
        var enm = $('#edtName').val();
        var eml = $('#edtEmail').val();
        var egp = $('#editSubForm input[name=edgrp]').val();
        var dataString = 'act=upd&sid=' + thisid + '&edName='+ enm + '&edEmail='+ eml + '&edgrp='+ egp;
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/subscr_query.asp',
        data:  dataString,
        success: function(){
                //alert(dataString);
                $('#successmsg').append("Edited!");
                $('#successmsg').fadeIn(1200, function(){$(this).fadeOut(2000);});
                },
        error: function(){
                $('#delpop').fadeIn(300);
                }
            });
    });
```

The form contains a submit button with the id **"editbtn"**. Form seems to process with out the database getting update with the current information.

I've tested the queryString on the subscr_query.asp page by entering the data that gets outputted from the form to the page directly, and db updated as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Title says "MySQL" and tags say "SQL Server" - which one is it now??

Comment: Sorry, it's actually SQL Server. But the database type doesn't matter in this case because the problem was the form processing before the Ajax had a chance to run. I changed the title of the question. Sorry again for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suspecting you're not preventing the default action; hence, it's submitting the form before performing the ajax request. Use `preventDefault`

```
$('#editbtn').click(function(e){
        var thisid = $('#edsid').val();
        var enm = $('#edtName').val();
        var eml = $('#edtEmail').val();
        var egp = $('#editSubForm input[name=edgrp]').val();
        var dataString = 'act=upd&sid=' + thisid + '&edName='+ enm + '&edEmail='+ eml + '&edgrp='+ egp;
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/subscr_query.asp',
        data:  dataString,
        success: function(){
                //alert(dataString);
                $('#successmsg').append("Edited!");
                $('#successmsg').fadeIn(1200, function(){$(this).fadeOut(2000);});
                },
        error: function(){
                $('#delpop').fadeIn(300);
                }
            });
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
    });
```